# How to use an int from one class and compare it to int's from other classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to make a slot machine game. I have searched other forums, but they all seem to be using the int's just a little bit differently then the way I'm trying to use them

I have 4 classes, here is a simple version:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ExampleCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;

        SlotLeft left = new SlotLeft();
        SlotMid mid = new SlotMid();
        SlotRight right = new SlotRight();

        left.left(a);
        mid.mid(b);
        right.right(c);

        if(a==b){
            System.out.println("text");
        }
        if(a==c){
             System.out.println("different text");
        }
        if(b==c){
            System.out.println("More text");
        }
        if(a==b&&a==c&&b==a&&b==c&&c==a&&c==b){
            System.out.println("last text");
        }
    }
}


//left class
import java.util.*;
public class SlotLeft {
    public void left(int a) {
        int 1;
    }
}
//mid class
import java.util.*;
public class SlotMid {
    public void mid(int b) {
        int b = 1;
    }
}

//right class
import java.util.*;
public class SlotRight {
    public void right(int c) {
        int c = 1;
    }        
}
```

The brackets may be messed up but that isn't my concern. I'm trying to set certain int's in the three classes,and then be able to give them that value in the main class and compare the three numbers. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Tried to make it more defined, sorry relatively new to Java.

Comment: Hmmm... nothing clear in your question. Sorry.

Comment: a, b, c, and d are undefined.

Comment: Since your methods left() arent' returning anything how do you expect to compare anything?

Comment: I'm assuming those `SlotN` methods are just stubs, because right now they just set a function-local variable, which is completely useless.

Comment: @HotLicks not only them. `left`, `mid` and `right` also

Comment: @Andremoniy - Yep, it's hard to find anything that IS defined.

Comment: For all who's complaining, it's obviously just example code. Instead of complaining about his lacking SSCCE, how about just editing to fix it. As for his actual problem, he states, "I'm trying to set certain int's in the three classes,and then be able to give them that value in the main class and compare the three numbers."

Comment: @Brian: I could spend my time fixing it (not rewarding), or moving on to a question that can be answered right away (which is rewarding). You get your questions answered by making the path to someone getting their reputation as short and easy as possible. This is how the game of SO is played, it's inherent in the way the system is set up, and complaints in comments aren't going to amount to anything.

Comment: @Brian - I read the description through twice and couldn't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: You cannot modify a method parameter in Java and have the modification reflected back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead of a class for each slot:

```
public static final int SLOT_LEFT = 0 ;
public static final int SLOT_MID = 1 ;
public static final int SLOT_RIGHT = 2 ;

int[] slots = new int[3];
```

set the value of a slot:

```
slots[SLOT_MID] = 1;
```

You also can integrate that all in a class

```
class SlotManager {
    public static final int SLOT_LEFT = 0 ;
    public static final int SLOT_MID = 1 ;
    public static final int SLOT_RIGHT = 2 ;

    int[] slots = new int[3];

    public void setSlot(int slotId, int value) {
       slots[slotId] = value;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly assigning a value to a parameter passed into your methods won't change it in the calling method. In other words:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        foo(i);
        System.out.println(i); // Prints "0", not "1"
    }

    public void foo(int i) {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

This prints `0`, not `1`. Again, direct assignment does not change the value in the calling method. Instead, do something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = foo();
        System.out.println(i); // Prints "1"
    }

    public int foo() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is contrary to reference passing in C/C++, of course, where this is possible using [pass-by-reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).

Comment: Possible, but not normal -- requires specific notation.